# 64bit HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I was reading this blog post [here](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/) about calculating hash collision probabilities.
As per the formula `1−(e^(−k(k−1)/2N))` where `k` is the number of entries and `N` is max_entries the hash collision probability for default Java hashmap should be `50%` with just 70 thousand entries.

This might seem counter intuitive since the max possible entry range is very large (4294967296). But it could be understood with the birthday paradox where probability reaches 99.9% with just 70 people.

Now the questions:

1. Am I understanding this right? Is Java Hashmap only usable with a few thousand entries?
2. Are there any plans to implement 64bit hashes in future versions of Java?
3. Is there a Map implementation provided by `Guava` or some other library that uses `long` based hashes instead of `integers`.

Comment: Why do you need that many objects in a single hashtable? If you're building a custom in-memory store that has special needs, then implementing a custom hashtable doesn't seem like it should be out of the question.

Comment: `Many` is a subjective term. I don't consider `70k` to be many in modern computing environments.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Collisions are indeed an issue, but simply increasing table size is not a viable solution.  A hash table (as defined in Intro to Algorithms) uses a direct-address table to store the hash buckets.  Because it's a direct-address table, the size before you actually start storing objects is relative to the total possible number of hashes in the 'universe' (by universe, I mean the universe as far the hash table is concerned).  If you were to actually use all of that available address space, your hash table, before you put anything in it, would be `2^30 * memory_address_size`, which is a lot (note that OpenJDK sets the limit on the number of objects in a hash map to `2^30`, not `2^32`).

The Java HashMap implementation actually starts, by default, with a hash universe size of 16 (I remember reading 8, but OpenJDK 8 JVM implementation is 16).  So when you put in an object, Java gets the integer result from `hashCode()` and finds the remainder from dividing by 16.  And that's the hash it uses.  By default, the Java hash map also uses a load factor of 0.75.  So it doesn't attempt to increase the size of the 'hash universe' until it's 75% full.  When it gets to that point, a new hash table is created, recalculating all of the hashes in the process with a new universe size double that of the previous table.  Which is an expensive operation.  So what I'm saying is, the Java HashMap aims to keep the map 75% full, and expects collisions.  And that correctly setting up your hash map can improve performance.  You can instantiate a hash map with an initial value, and also a load factor of your choosing.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap(128, 0.5f);
```

Note that in the OpenJDK implementation, you can't choose a load factor less than 0.25, or greater than 4:

```
float lf = Math.min(Math.max(0.25f, loadFactor), 4.0f);
```

There are actually two HashMap implementations in java, `HashMap`, and `IdentityHashMap`, and they use two different methods of storing objects that collide.  `IdentityHashMap` places an object whose hash collides with another object into the next available bucket.  Each bucket only contains a single object.  It also uses `==` for comparison, rather than `.equals()`, so you can really only use primitive data types for the key.  It's a bit faster than HashMap however.

The HashMap implementation uses a linked list in each bucket to store objects that have the same hash.  Since Java 8, once any linked list gets 8 or more objects, the linked list will be refactored into a [tree](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/04/hashmap-performance-improvements-in.html).  If your objects don't have `Comparable` implemented, then this won't have any effect.  So it pays to have your objects implement `Comparable`.  But this means we can quantify the cost of a collision.  At worst case, it's `O(n)` for a linked list, but with a tree, it's at worst case `O(logn)`.  And by worst case, I mean when all of your objects end up in the same bucket.

So when that blog talks about the chance of a collision, it really doesn't matter if two objects out of 70,000 collide.  It doesn't matter if a thousand of them do.  Collisions matter when your objects **do not have an even distribution of hashes**.  From an o-notation perspective, having to loop through a linked list of size 2 in a hash map of size 70k is still O(1).  If those thousand collisions happen in the same hash bucket, then you do have a real problem.  But that is a **problem with your hash implementation**, not the lack of 64 bit addressing.

There are ways of hashing perfectly.  Such as [dynamic perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing) and [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).  These use multiple hashing algorithms to try to prevent hash collisions.  Dynamic hashing uses two tables, one of which is quite large in an attempt to avoid any collisions.  But this incurs a serious memory cost, which is not to be forgotten about.

So, to answer your question:

1. No, HashMaps are usable with a lot more than a few thousand entries.  Collisions are only destructive if you have a serious problem with unevenly distributed hashes.  Implement `Comparable` on your objects if you can't fix uneven hashing.
2. No, it wouldn't be necessary.  With a 75% load factor, which HashMap currently uses, you'd need 805306368 entries before a Java HashMap would consider using more than the hash space currently available to it.
3. There's an implementation of a cuckoo hashing map on github, and a few other implementations floating around.  I've never seen it being used in anger though.  I reckon you're much better off working on fixing your hashes, and tuning the initial size and load factor of your map though.

Answer (score 2):

Java-Hashmap still guarantees that you get the correct object back.
The only impact actually is for performance that in case of collisions speed reduces. Which is negligible in most of the cases. Only if you add a really high amount of values you will see it. (Close to Max-Entries)

I don't think there is a long-Hashmap implementation directly because the Array-Size is bound in Java for `Integer.Maxvalue`. If you want create a bigger Hashmap you need to build more-dimensional arrays which probably often would increase the performance more negative than the collisions do.

Especially the memory-footprint would grow so high that the theoretical CPU-Advantage will be killed by GC-Overhead, Object Allocation, higher basic querying time (time to get a value without a collision)

So I don't have any implementation using longvalue, but you could do something like this. Some Pseudo-Java-Code:

```
long key = ...; // your key.
int key1 = key >> 32;
int key2 = (int) key;
HashMap<IntegerKey1, HashMap<IntegerKey2, Value>> ...
//Use more complicated methods to add and receive values.
```

However using such an implementation you will see that it does not work.

Comment: Two points: 1. Performance impact from collisions is not negligible. It is pretty severe. 2. Array size limitation should be easy to work around with an implementation that uses multiple backing arrays, as is done in incremental dynamic re-sizing.

Comment: 3. Your third point about larger hashmaps isn't true. Could you explain the same principles for creating hashmap with `int` wouldn't scale to `long`?

Comment: This gets an interesting discussion. For point 1: Yes worst-case Performance is O(log n) or even O(n)? instead of Best Case O(1) . So for High values it is definitely severe. However I am using HashMaps with > 10 million entries and I never realised any major performance decrease there. (Although the datastore in my Applications are important but not the only time critical application) - it may be worth to check it.

Comment: Point 2 + 3: I mainly thought of my idea here, which really should not work - that this could be vastly improved by only add new backing arrays if necessary is a good hint.

Answer (score 2):

The correct question to ask is: what is the probability of having enough  keys in one bucket to turn O(1) into O(N)?

This basically means that all keys are evenly distributed between small fixed number of buckets, ignoring the rest of N buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Hash tables in Java (and in other languages) work post-collision.

The hashing mechanism exists to quickly find a starting index in an array, typically by applying the modulus division operator (remainder of a division)

```
array_index = hash % index_size;
```

At that index, the key entry is typically not the stored item.  Typically it is a linked-list that then contains the keys (and values).  This means that in a collision situation, the performance degrades, but only degrades to O(n) over the collection of all elements that will collide.  That partition is much smaller (like you mentioned 2 in 70,000) than the overall data set.  The speed gains are significant.  In other words, you are likely to have a hastable that looks like

```
 Node[] entries;
 private class Node {
    Key k;
    Value v;
    Node next;
 }
```

Rather than

```
 Pair[] entries
 private class Pair {
   Key k,
   Value v
 }
```

There *are* other means of resolving hash collision, basically one is to "store in next index", where instead of maintaining a linked list, you put the item in the first index bucket below that's empty.  This saves some complexity in storage, but makes retrieval more complicated over time, and as a result is less used.

Hash collisions are the primary reason why Java's hash tables (and any good implementation of a hash table) has a secondary check to see if the two key objects "equals" each other.  The hash is used to find one (or possibly more) candidates, and each candidate key is then checked with the "equals" method to determine if the candidate key was indeed the requested one, or was merely a key-colliding one.